# Why the new user can't login postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, psql

`postgres` can login postgresql via my bash console:

```
psql -U postgres
```

I have created a new user with the such same password as `postgres`.

```
postgres=# CREATE USER debian  PASSWORD 'xxxxxx';
CREATE ROLE
```

Make the user as superuser:

```
postgres=# ALTER USER debian  WITH SUPERUSER;
ALTER ROLE
```

Now i want login the database with user `debian`:

```
psql -U debian
psql: error: FATAL:  database "debian" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

`psql` assumes you want to connect to a database with the same name as the user if you don't specify a database name

So you need to specify the database to which you

```
psql -U debian -d postgres
```